# Footer not showing in full width in the mobile

Tags: html, css, meta

I am designing a web without meta viewport. I want to show my web on mobile as well as desktop.There is problem in the comperision of home(index) and inside page.Home page header and footer showing properly but on the inside page header showing good but not as well as home page and footer not showing properly in full width.Plz help me Thank you
there is problem only for mobile and tab
http://websum.in/prome/concepts.php

Answer (score 0):

Please paste html code and css code other wise cannot full help you. And or your code show some example through **codepen or jsfiddle**  I see you have not set any media queries for you need to set some media queries for mobile formats some where along those lines you should look into bootstrap to see how they are done.

I had a look in firebug on your website could not see any media queries

Example only

```
@media (max-width: 648px) {
 .footercontainer {
   width: 90%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: just realized you didn't say you use Twitter bootstrap. This example requires Twitter bootstrap, or you could fetch the Css classes from there.

What you could do is make sure the text blocks in the footer appear centered and underneath each other on mobile. Something like this:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row hidden-xs">
        Desktop footer 
    </div>

    <div class="row visible-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            Icons and stuff.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            Copyright.
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```